# strtod and underflow

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, type-conversion

I would like to detect underflow when converting string to double in C++ (Visual C++ 2010) using `strtod` function. The code below doesn't work as I expect although I did it according to `strtod`'s documentation:

```
 char numStr[] = "123456.122111111123123123123132123123123123123124434345345";
 char* pEnd;
 double d = strtod(numStr, &pEnd);
 int errorNum = errno;
 if (errorNum == ERANGE) // this should be true
 {
  // underflow occurred
 }
```

Using the debugger, I found out that `errorNum` is always set to `0` and `ERANGE` is `34`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing "loss of precision" with "underflow".  You would get underflow with input like `1.0e-1000`.  `strtod` doesn't directly report a loss of precision, but you could try changing the last digit and reparsing, or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

That value doesn't underflow.  It's (much) greater than the smallest normal positive double.  Even the last place alone (5*10^-51) is.  The smallest normal 64-bit IEEE double is 2^−1022.

Answer (score 0):

There is no underflow in your code. Underflow would be something like 0.000(1000 zeros)001 getting converted to 0. What you're talking about is inexactness, and testing for it is difficult. Even converting back to a string with `snprintf` and doing a string comparison would not necessarily work since `snprintf` is not required to produce exact results, only enough to reconstruct the value with `strtod`. What you're attempting is a hard problem.